# Update values in object in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, object, key, session-storage

I have this object stored in sessionstorage:

```
0: {FromName: "FName", FromLastName: "", FromAddress: "F Street", FromCountry: "Portugal", FromCity: "FC",…}
1: {FromName: "FName", FromLastName: "", FromAddress: "F Street", FromCountry: "Portugal", FromCity: "FC",…}
2: {FromName: "", FromLastName: "", FromAddress: "", FromCountry: "", FromCity: "", FromPostCode: "",…}
```

It displays a list of Shopping Cart Items.

When I'm at the Cart, I have a button that makes me able to display the values in a form and it's already getting the right values from the sessionStorage.

The question is, how can I update the values, using the displayed form and the updated the object correctly?

This is the code that grabs the correct values from the object in sessionstorage:

```
  e.preventDefault();

  var itemsInCart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('productList'));
  var ID = $(this).data('id');

  for (var i = 0; i < itemsInCart.length; i++) {

    var itemsinCartID = itemsInCart[i].keyID;

    if (ID == itemsinCartID) {

    $('.product-image').attr('src', itemsInCart[i].Product);
    $('#message').val(itemsInCart[i].Message);

    // from inputs
    var fromName = $('#from-name-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromName);
    var fromLastName = $('#from-last-name-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromLastName);
    var fromAddress = $('#from-address-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromAddress);
    var fromCountry = $('#from-country-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromCountry);
    var fromCity = $('#from-city-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromCity);
    var fromPostCode = $('#from-postalcode-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromPostCode);
    var fromPhone = $('#from-phone-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromPhone);

    // to inputs
     var toName = $('#to-name-input').val(itemsInCart[i].ToName);
     var toLastName = $('#to-last-name-input').val(itemsInCart[i].ToLastName);
     var toAddress = $('#to-address-input').val(itemsInCart[i].ToAddress);
     var toCountry = $('#to-country-input').val(itemsInCart[i].ToCountry);
     var toCity = $('#to-city-input').val(itemsInCart[i].ToCity);
     var toPostCode = $('#to-postalcode-input').val(itemsInCart[i].ToPostCode);
     var toPhone = $('#to-phone-input').val(itemsInCart[i].ToPhone);
    break;
    }
  }

});
```

This is the form that is filled with the code above:
[image]

And then I want to use hit the "edit message" button in the form to update the new values that i changed in the form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. You want to update sessionStorage item with new one from the form. Yes?
I would consider change the code a little bit to:

```
const tempObject = {
  FromName: $('#from-name-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromName),
  FromLastName = $('#from-last-name-input').val(itemsInCart[i].FromLastName)
}
Object.assign(itemsInCart, tempObject)
sessionStorage.setItem('productList', JSON.strigify(itemsInCart));
```

Comment: This code is the code that fills the forms.
Then,  I want to change the values in the form, hit the submit button and update the old values with new ones.

Comment: When is "then"?

Comment: i updated my question, i think you can understand now.

Comment: it's replace the object in sessionstorage with a new one, but it's erasing the other entries of the object.

```0: {FromName: "FName", FromLastName: "", FromAddress: "F Street", FromCountry: "Portugal", FromCity: "FC",…}
```

Comment: Ok. so you have an array in sessionStorage. Do you want to update an entry of that array or push a new one?

Comment: Ok, so you have to to provide an id for that entry somewhere.
And use Object.assign(itemsInCart[id], tempObject)